# How to specify a Comparator for a MapFactory

Tags: java

I have the following code that works correctly:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(input)
            .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0],
                    TreeMap::new, toList()));
```

But I need the TreeMap to sort in descending order. I've tried:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(input)
            .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0],
                    new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)), toList()));
```

But I get the error "Cannot find symbol compare to object".

How do I get the TreeMap to accept a Comparator? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Elliott It's a downstream collector: Collectors.toList. I've imported the Collectors class statically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a `Supplier<Map>`, which you can make with a lambda like this:

```
() -> new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a))
```

also since you just want to reverse the order, you could use the method for that provided in the `Comparator` class:

```
() -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: I have to write it like a lambda. Of course! Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There may well be another way to do it, but I got it working with

```
String[] input = { "a", "b", "c" };
Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a));
map.putAll(Arrays.stream(input).collect(
    groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0], TreeMap::new, toList())));
System.out.println(map);
```

Output is

```
{c=[c], b=[b], a=[a]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the comparator to tree map as below only then it will store the values in some order as per the implementation of the comparator. The below code will allow you to store the values in a descending order.

```
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String string1, String string2) {
    if (string1.compareTo(string2) > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (string1.compareTo(string2) < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    };
});
```

The other alternative way is to get the key in descending order using the below API from TreeMap and then retrieve the value from it.

```
Set<String> keySet = treeMap.descendingKeySet();
for (String key : keySet) {
    System.out.println(treeMap.get(key));
}
```